# Redirect with a variable

Tags: php, html, redirect

I re-did my portfolio site recently, and I'm trying to make it so that when someone clicks a link to my and old project (ie  /philosophy.php) that it takes the name of that file (philosophy) and then adds it to an id indicator # and loads to my new page with that ID selected so it automatically scrolls to that project.

Click link > http://www.studioimbrue.com/philosophy.php
Redirect > http://www.studioimbrue.com/#philosophy

I am using this right now: `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; URL=http://www.studioimbrue.com/">`  and I added `#<!--#echo var="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" -->` but it just comes up as (none).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `.htaccess` file to your server root

and include this in it:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /#$1 [R=301,NE]
```

Otherwise use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; URL=http://www.studioimbrue.com/#<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php');?>">
```

Comment: This will just add philosophy.php to everything, it needs to be a variable pulled from the original link (so if it were .com/book.php it would redirect to .com/#book)

Comment: This redirects endlessly (at least on my server). You need some RewriteCond. You also need the NE (no escape) flag to correctly handle the hash.

Comment: This works!

I tried using the PHP one but the URL it sent ended up being this: http://www.studioimbrue.com/#<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php');?>

Comment: It sounds like that is not a HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add some rewrite condition not allowing the redirection when there actually is a file with that name, as well as specifying the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.php$ /#$1 [R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: This will do what you want BUT you must add the NE flag otherwise your hash mark will be escaped and the browser won't read it.

f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.php$ /#$1 [R=301,NC,NE]

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can achieve the same thing with PHP

```
$newName  = 'http://www.studioimbrue.com/#' . substr($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], 1, -3);
header('Location: $newName');
die();
```

But I think doing this with .htaccess is the better way.